# MySQL slave not updating / syncing

Tags: mysql, replication, slave

I had a MySQL slave that was running on one server, but I needed to migrate to a new server.  I shut down my slave on the original server, copied the DB over to the new server and launched MySQL.

I updated the Master configuration by using `Change Master To`, indicating the master server name, the master_log_pos (the same value of exec_master_log_pos on the decommissioned slave), etc.

I started the slave and ran into a couple of errors:

1. The server-id on the new slave accidentally matched the master server-id
2. The temp folder on the new slave did not exist.

I corrected the two errors, and restarted MySQL.

In my slave status now, I no longer see any errors, but `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` does not increment.  The `Read_Master_Log_Pos` keeps changing, which implies that it is receiving the master updates, but the slave does not seem to be executing the changes in the log file.

```
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 171716503
Exec_Master_log_Pos: 168097060
```

How can I force the slave to start executing the statements in the log?  I've tried to stop and start the slave (both using slave start/stop and restarting mysql itself), but neither seem to have any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a crashed table and MySQL was not able to run any updates to the slave until the table was repaired.  I ran `mysqlcheck -r` on it, fixed the table, restarted the slave, and everything synced back up fine.

Hopefully this can help someone in the future who gets stuck on a similar problem.